# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given , announcement bot for discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My bot is actually having a problem with running the command and idk why its keep giving me this error ,The bot that I am using is for a announcement purpose on discord, So this the code that I am using in the bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
import time
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "+")
client.remove_command("help")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(client.user.name)
   print("Online")
   print("-------")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def announce(ctx,*,message):
    embed = discord.Embed("Information",description=message,color=0x9200ea)
    embed.set_footer(text="Made by Elanovic#7940")
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.channel,embed=embed)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

And this is the error I get from the cmd:

```
Ignoring exception in command announce:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\Desktop\PYTHON\bot.py", line 19, in announce
    embed = discord.Embed("Information",description=message,color=0x9200ea)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

As well all of this is happening in the cmd and the bot take commands from the discord channel by the command `+announce`

but the bot respond with the above in the cmd

Comment: The parameters to `discord.Embed` doesn't take a string as a first parameter, and the listed attribute name is colour, not color https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is a simple command's attribute error.

The syntax for an Embed is:

```
discord.Embed(Name="Embed", description='This is an EMBED', color=0xff00ff)
```

#### Where is the error in your code?

The error is in the EMBED code and it can also be seen in the Traceback.

```
embed = discord.Embed("Information",description=message,color=0x9200ea)
```

You must be trying to put the name of the embed but you didn't write it correctly.

So, I would just say that change this line to:

```
discord.Embed(name='Information', description=message, color=0x9200ea)
```

This would completely solve your issue.

---

In the end, just a simple piece of advice from my side. Always check the Traceback for the error. In the traceback you can see this:

```
1.File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
2.    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
3.  File "C:\Users\Hasanfox69\Desktop\PYTHON\bot.py", line 19, in announce
4.    embed = discord.Embed("Information",description=message,color=0x9200ea)
    TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

The line number 4 (according to my marking) shows that the error is in the Embed code so you can simply solve it by just knowing where it is coming from.

---

I was glad that I could help. Please feel free to ask if you still have any problem. :)

Thank You! :D